# Parse.com CloudCode beforeSave trigger errors

Tags: parse-platform, triggers, parse-cloud-code

Context: parse.com CloudCode, executing beforeSave() trigger on data object object update.

Getting a rash of unexplained errors in simple trigger function (code below). The errors are mostly

> Result: Uncaught undefined

but there are also several

> Result: Execution timed out

The code is simple, I have checked it to the point where I don't think this is an error due to the code, but including it anyway since I know people will ask to see it.

This seems (seems!) to be an issue in Parse itself, which I've been unable to solve.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("LogoItem", function(request, response) {

var name = request.object.get("productName");
if (typeof name == "undefined") {
    name = "";
}
request.object.set("lowercaseName", name.toLowerCase());

response.success();  // Tells parse not to cancel save
```

});

**My question is, has anyone seen this and been able to get any handle on a solution?**

---

*Below is some additional detail (logs from parse) that likely won't be too useful (but never know)...*

```
E2016-03-14T14:12:26.306Z] - v643 Ran job ShopSenseJob with:
  Input: {"plan":"paid"}
  Result: ERROR: startDownloadItems() failed with error [undefined: undefined] undefined: undefined

E2016-03-14T14:11:01.536Z] - v643 before_save triggered for LogoItem as master:
  Input: {"original":{"activeURL":"http://api.shopstyle.com/action/apiVisitRetailer?id=486671765\u0026pid=uid4009-26060253-59","category":5,"createdAt":"2016-03-14T13:41:07.487Z","imageURL":"https://resources.shopstyle.com/pim/aa/92/aa9286b799d7640f276657fa5e41ee92_best.jpg","importMarkerTag":6624,"lowercaseName":"mid rise skinny with knee holes in marie vintage blue","objectId":"8o9e8nMF7m","productName":"Mid Rise Skinny With Knee Holes In Marie Vintage Blue","referenceURL":"http://www.shopstyle.com/p/7-for-all-mankind-mid-rise-skinny-with-knee-holes-in-marie-vintage-blue/486671765?pid=uid4009-26060253-59","ssBrandId":3,"ssBrandName":"7 For All Mankind","ssDate":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-12-05T00:00:00.000Z"},"ssId":486671765,"ssRetailerId":193,"thumbnailURL":"https://resources.shopstyle.com/pim/aa/92/aa9286b799d7640f276657fa5e41ee92_best.jpg","updatedAt":"2016-03-14T13:41:07.487Z"},"update":{"importMarkerTag":1556}}

  Result: Execution timed out

E2016-03-14T14:10:21.498Z] - v643 Ran job ShopSenseJob with:
  Input: {}
  Result: ERROR: startDownloadItems() failed with error [undefined: undefined] undefined: undefined

E2016-03-14T14:08:18.638Z] - v643 before_save triggered for LogoItem as master:
  Input: {"original":{"activeURL":"http://api.shopstyle.com/action/apiVisitRetailer?id=490062821\u0026pid=uid4009-26060253-59","category":2,"createdAt":"2016-03-14T13:40:12.971Z","imageURL":"https://resources.shopstyle.com/pim/20/cb/20cb7387834dd02ac9d950bde0f57b83_best.jpg","importMarkerTag":1556,"lowercaseName":"baggu basic tote in brown","objectId":"I4UTiUMnUG","productName":"Baggu Basic Tote In Brown","referenceURL":"http://www.shopstyle.com/p/baggu-basic-tote-in-brown/490062821?pid=uid4009-26060253-59","ssBrandId":-1,"ssBrandName":"","ssDate":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-12-03T00:00:00.000Z"},"ssId":490062821,"ssRetailerId":193,"thumbnailURL":"https://resources.shopstyle.com/pim/20/cb/20cb7387834dd02ac9d950bde0f57b83_best.jpg","updatedAt":"2016-03-14T14:06:12.708Z"},"update":{"importMarkerTag":1556}}

  Result: Uncaught undefined

E2016-03-14T14:08:18.225Z] - v643 Ran job ShopSenseJob with:
  Input: {}
  Result: ERROR: startDownloadItems() failed with error [undefined: undefined] undefined: undefined

E2016-03-14T14:06:12.824Z] - v643 before_save triggered for LogoItem as master:
  Input: {"original":{"activeURL":"http://api.shopstyle.com/action/apiVisitRetailer?id=489915836\u0026pid=uid4009-26060253-59","category":2,"createdAt":"2016-03-14T13:40:13.193Z","imageURL":"https://resources.shopstyle.com/pim/14/ef/14ef17ff769227c4293892e770fcf50a_best.jpg","importMarkerTag":1556,"lowercaseName":"basic tote in black","objectId":"JQ7GuRjfgH","productName":"Basic Tote In Black","referenceURL":"http://www.shopstyle.com/p/baggu-basic-tote-in-black/489915836?pid=uid4009-26060253-59","ssBrandId":25820,"ssBrandName":"Baggu","ssDate":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-12-02T00:00:00.000Z"},"ssId":489915836,"ssRetailerId":193,"thumbnailURL":"https://resources.shopstyle.com/pim/14/ef/14ef17ff769227c4293892e770fcf50a_best.jpg","updatedAt":"2016-03-14T14:06:10.013Z"},"update":{"importMarkerTag":1556}}

  Result: Execution timed out

E2016-03-14T14:05:23.844Z] - v643 Ran job ShopSenseJob with:
  Input: {}
  Result: ERROR: startDownloadItems() failed with error [undefined: undefined] undefined: undefined
```

Comment: also having this, see https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/223